# Kernel panic.../vmlinuz not found loop. I'm stuck for a month!

Tags: kernel

I have been stuck, and tried for so long now, I need help!

I don't know what I did then I am unable to boot into my ubuntu 14.04, installed on partition SDB8!
I have reinstalled grub2 many times now, but still nothing happens. I booted into Live CD, and see the opened the volume that has my linux, and realized there is no vmlinuz file. So, I went to my flash disk that has live cd, copied cASPER folder, which has vmlinuz and pasted on my volume, then tried to reboot.

Grub menu I pressed edit, and changed the linux /vmlinuz to linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi then exit menu. rebooting, it hits the black screen saying KERNEL PANIC, VFS not syncing blabla.... I boot back into liveCD, not I can't see the volume with my linux. I opened GParted, and saw SDB8 is now mounted on /CDROM, and I can't unmount it.

I don't want to format my computer, I have way too much data on linux volume. Please help me!!

Attached is the results.txt from bootinfoscript (bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net):

[partitions](http://pastebin.com/VBnmH8EE)

Comment: from grub.cfg you still have old kernel on it. Are u able to boot using older release?

Comment: Sorry I am a newbee! I don't know how to. When I start the computer and see grub menu, I have only 2 choices, SBD2 for Windows, and SDB8(which seems to be SDB7 now) for ubuntu. Chooosing ubuntu says /vmlinuz file not found.  hitting "e" on grub menu, I set vmlinuz path, then that's when it runs and brings kernel panic black screen!!!

Comment: does the vmlinuz version are the same with the one missing? If not you will have this kind of behaviour due to `initramfs`.

Comment: I believe it is the same, as this Live CD is one I used to install it. It's annoying how I can't access the volume anymore, saying it's booted to /CDROM!

Comment: No you cant use vmlinuz for live cd. Its not the same.

Comment: You need to verify the initramfs version on the os. Can you still select which kernel to load??

Comment: I copied it from USB which acts as my live CD. it was actually under Casper folder. I guess I messed up, but is there a way to roll back or to improve the situation? Thanks @AizuddinZali for your support!

Comment: no I unfortunately can't. Grub menu brings z3 options. 1, SDB2 for windows, SDB8 for ubuntu, more options (where it brings 2 or 4 options, recovery. clicking each of them says /vmlinuz not found)!

Comment: Best shot now is to copy vmlinuz and initramfs from another ubuntu installation. You cant use initramfs for live cd.

Comment: have any idea how I can access the volume? Through live CD, I can't see the volume. GParted shows it's mounted on /CDROM, and when I try to unmount it with sudo umount /cdrom, it says device busy, try to force unmount it, with no luck! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Put down the keyboard. Back away from the computer. Further. Now go outside and play with a stick.